# Can I download apps from the US app store if I'm using a different store?

Tags: ios-appstore

Can I download apps from the US apps Store even if I'm currently using the italian store ?

For example, I would like to download [Spotify](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/spotify/id324684580?mt=8), which is not available in the Italian store:

Should I change credit card? Or can I use the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [EmmEff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29282/downloading-apps-from-the-us-apps-store-even-if-im-on-another-store-now/29294#29294) answer, we do this in  South AFrica quite often.

- Register a US account using a valid US Address (The US Yellow Pages Helps)
- Do not register a credit card
- Download free apps, books, music etc.
- Purchase US iTunes gift cards online and load onto account
- Buy software, books and music.

<sub>Please note, South Africa has a severely restricted App Store, and we cannot purchase games, music or books any other way, and due to legal issues with classification of items, will most likely never be able too</sub>

Comment: Thanks, what about using paypal instead of gift cards ?

Comment: @Patrick As long as it's a US paypal account it will be fine. Apple checks countries quite strictly.

Comment: I've decided to buy an US gift card. Should I buy it on the Apple website ? And how can I reveice it in Netherlands rather than US ?

Comment: I see only 2 solutions: to buy them on ebay or another website and ask to ship to europe, to ask a friend to buy them in US and pass me the code. Correct ?

Comment: @Patrick In South Africa we have local companies that sell them and send you the code electronically. Not sure if this is available in Europe.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create an account on the US store.  Apple probably won't accept your foreign credit card either (at least they do not in Canada), so you need US gift cards to create an account.  Google for more information.

Comment: How do I get US gift cards in Europe ?

Comment: I see only 2 solutions: to buy them on ebay or another website and ask to ship to europe, to ask a friend to buy them in US and pass me the code. Correct ?