# How to bypass country restrictions on App Store?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ios-appstore

I want to download an iPhone app which is not accessible from my country (India). How can I bypass the country restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

You need an iTunes account for the country-specific store in order to download apps restricted to certain countries. If the app is not free, you also will need either a credit card issued in that country or some iTunes gift cards (also from that country).

Comment: For git cards etc see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29282/can-i-download-apps-from-the-us-app-store-if-im-using-a-different-store/29296#29296

Answer (score -2):

**How to bypass country restrictions on App Store?
*I want to download an iPhone app which is not accessible from my country (India). How can I bypass the country restrictions?***

Hi Prasanth S here is two solutions involving VPN and DNS. These solutions can also be implemented on a router level but that is another topic.

## By pass County Restrictions, block websites, run a vpn, select an open dns- all OPEN SOURCE:

**Method 1 VPN:**
The apps openvpn and open vpn spider work together. If these apps are blocked I encourage you to try the DNS soloution provided below.

TIP: OpenVpn Spider will show an ad when you attempt to load a profile into Openvpn (your actully loading a certificate into a protocol)- so click a different server in less than 20-30 seconds (after the ad can be closed) or soemthing and you won't be tracked through that ad to the server.

( Otherwise, the ad (likely google) will know which vpn your on. If you care- yes you can view this from either a non signed in account or another- in account info- you can also opt out of the tracking! )

You can select a country in OpenVPN Spider app at the top.

---

**Method 2 ) Change your DNS**

Now search for your carriers DNS settings, write them down or copy them to a note. Now search for a subsitute- type "OpenDNS servers   " into google/duckduckgo/ whatever. If you were successful in turning on a VPN on your iphone or ipad so far, you can choose to match this county with the DNS server by searching specifically for it. 
Google's server- is not really DNS open but it does unblock sometimes- the VPN will automatically be connected to Google's service anyhow. You may attempt to block it as well if you want and divert traffic to a new DNS setting as well- but this will cause most google apps to error and logout- given how prelevant they are I hestiate to suggest that.
Google servers for DNS are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Now go to settings--> General --> Restritions
Turn it on- make a code
Now enable Adult restrictions
You will now see a white list (allow) and a block list

Enter the carrier DNS into the block list (the numbers- which by the way are called an octet- 8 groups of binary numbers showed in decimal form to make it easier on you :) . You can also block a port by entering a semicolon : after the digits. So DNS is port 53. Your entry would look like this-

xxx.xx.xxx.xx: 53

where the ip address is represented prior to the semicolon.

Now scroll up and enter several websites into the allow list- you can add entries in here- just add the DNS server you want to use. Keep in mind the OpenVPN servers do die after a while. You'll also want to add common websites you visit. Some sites are automatically blocked - such as porn- so if you want them you can allow it here. Only make each "similar" entry once.

Putting VPN together with DNS blocking may not be completely necessary but it should unblock you and hide the activity. I'd also download a tor type app for browsing- using this after connecting to the VPN. It sounds like there's not much freedom there...

**Method 3 ON WIFI**

You may also want to block your home high speed internet's DNS as well. So when you connect to wifi you can bypass the app store block.

Simply find the settings by either going on routers homepage (you can block them there as well sometimes) and noting them.

### If you don't have access to the router- simply select the connection in your Wifi settings on your iphone- select manal and copy all the info but the DNS and replace it with what you would like. If you do this prior to selecting a connection agreement and change the last part of the IP address (just extorporlate from what the machine gave you) you can in fact bypass the connection agreement as well if it exists (such as at hotel) .

**EXTRA: 
Other hidden features of Restricted Websites besides Restricting Websites:**

A note on Google HangOuts- this app will also change the number its coming from depdnign on the server you choose.

Actually - in the opposite of this I usually choose to allow accounts.google.com to prevent the logout or problems with their services.
You can also block ( or allow- as in new lines for below) a range of ports such as 81-20000.

Additionally you can refer to the phones local host and block or allow a service on the phone- i.e. an app - for example Google HangOuts uses a specific port. There are also security features you can implement beyond what Apple has provided in restrictions- such as an entire firewall. To refer to the local host, type the IP address

127.0.0.1 or I believe "localhost" (no quotes) works as well. Same thing with the semicolon and the range. [ This is incoming ports , where as an IP address will be treated as outgoing ]
So If we want to block internet entirely for HTTP (the web) we can enter

127.0.0.1:80

If I want to block ports above 80 I can enter

xxx.xx.xxx.xx: 81-20000

Now your use is just governed by the law and there is less if any tracking if you combine this with the other methods listed here . Hopefully this works for you! Thanks for reading.
-Mail

Comment: Strictly speaking this doesn't answer the OP's question - or, it only *partially* answers it. The missing bit is that the OP also has to have an account for the iOS App Store for the country they want to download it from, so they're going to need to use/setup another Apple ID in that store as well. For example, if they want to download an app from the US App Store, they will need an Apple ID account *based* in the US to do so.